# Dynamic add a Smart Contract

Tags: corda

For custom smart contract is very useful for some case like template and flexible for business requirement? for now that have not been released. if something do this thing put into off-chain system and only related the reference into chain of smart contract. is it the best practice?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean exactly by dynamic smart contracts. Can you add some more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: sometime we want to define a new smart-contract of state or a new verify rule that have to stop dapp server then add it into to launch. do we have a interface or plug-in to trigger and load this smart-contract into blockchain like ETH wallet (abi function) or fabric( initiate or install a chaincode)

Answer (score 0):

There is no dynamic loading of CorDapp code currently. You have to power down the node, add the new or modified CorDapp to the node's `plugins` folder, then restart the node.

In the future, Corda is expected to implement "hot" reloading, so you will be able to install or update the node's CorDapps while the node is running.